# Von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of von Neumann algebras. Let H denote the direct sum$\Sigma_{i\in I} H_i$ of Hilbert spaces $\{H_i\}_{i\in I}$. Every vector $h=\{h_i\}$ in H is denoted by $\Sigma_{i\in I}h_i$. For each bounded sequence $\{x_i\}$ in $M= \Sigma M_i$, we define an operator x on H by $x\Sigma h_i=\Sigma x_ih_i$.

Why is M a von Neumann algebra?

Answer (score 1):

For another take on the idea in Michael's answer, if $p_k\in\oplus M_j$ is the net with $I_k$ in the $k^{\rm th}$ coordinate and zero elsewhere, then any $T\in M'$ has to satisfy $Tp_j=p_jT$. It follows that $$ (\oplus M_j)'=\oplus M_j'.$$ Now it follows immediately, from the double commutant theorem, that 
$$
(\oplus M_j)''=\oplus M_j''=\oplus M_j. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

By the double commutant theorem: $t \in B(H)$ in the commutant $M'$ of $M$ if and only if ($p_i$ denotes the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate)

$$
p_i t p_j = 0, \;\; \forall {i \neq j} 
$$

and

$$
p_i t p_i \in M_i' \subset B(H_i).
$$

Similarly, $s \in M''$ if and only if

$$
p_i s p_j = 0, \;\; \forall {i \neq j} 
$$

and

$$
p_i s p_i \in M_i'' = M_i\subset B(H_i),
$$

i.e. $s \in M$.